# How scrape a webpage with http request that does not work upon modification and restoration?

Tags: curl, web-scraping, httprequest

https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2010-22619-002

The above page is very hard to **scrape**. If I use chrome devtools to figure out the raw HTTP request, I can use curl (using some command like the following) to download. But once I start to modify the curl comamnd, it stops working. It will not work even I change the command back to the original one. This makes it very hard to figure out what are essential in the command. And why the curl is not working persistently?

Does anybody know what is going on? And how to scrape the webpage in this case? Thanks.

```
curl 'https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2010-22619-002' \
-XGET \
-H 'Cookie: PN_ACCESSTIME=1590443949351; D_HID=B2D7CBC8-9F78-3FF8-AF85-DBCA2549B75C; D_IID=6B45E04A-C23B-396B-BDA5-2278E4DC69CF; D_UID=2C3DC3A0-B486-3D0E-82B0-EFD89851CC75; D_ZID=B3CD9409-DCFA-39F9-8652-3F5AA1F661D8; D_ZUID=B2082E64-CC85-303A-98CA-CDB24B2136AC; ERIGHTS=9A7oTmdcDdNOOLQMkNE8KlCjLviB8Xi3-18x2dZGD2l5wwGgbsoix2BefrHXeAx3Dx3Dbxxx2FXl26couzYEndq9u24Mgx3Dx3D-MBjPj5HMO68xxf2gzQu6x2BXAx3Dx3D-jtx2Bu62wmWz8dEf2Tx2F743Xwx3Dx3D; currency=USD; defaultLocale=en-US; REFRESH_SESSION=false; PN_HOST=https%3A%2F%2Fpsycnet.apa.org; PN_MY=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.apa.org; PN_RC=false; connect.sid=s%3AIQ8oE9IASAXKwd6fs8kA9fX5R1ZT23ha.kGTspyZebDpWFIJWOunkfoKjp%2BmZlbi9QLoUwsPhlpM; D_SID=128.194.2.118:ECe+lQDTjpdBqy5goEKecyo/42Mjgbyb/Kki+4UTgVc; _ga=GA1.2.1866629999.1579333247' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate' \
-H 'Host: psycnet.apa.org' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-us' \
-H 'Referer: https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2010-22619-002' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive'
```

Comment: this website renders data using javascript. You'll have to use `selenium` to get the data. Furthermore, you'll need to be very careful when browsing this website using selenium because it has measures in place that can detect and block IP addresses that use automated browsers.

Comment: That is not the point. Even JavaScript needs HTTP requests. The question is why the HTTP request shown does not work persistently.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response headers you'll see this:

```
X-Distil-CS: MISS
```

[Distil Networks](https://help.distilnetworks.com/hc/en-us) (now Imperva) is a bot management solution. Your odds of successfully scraping this site are quite slim.

Comment: What is used by Distil Networks to tell what requests are from a bot?

Comment: Not only will they never tell you that (that's how these companies make their money), but also they change it all the time...

Comment: But are there any published work of bot detect methods that can be used to guess what they could do?